# want to add frame in mkmapview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview

I have a MKmapView in my application. now i want to add frame im my MKmapView. I have written the code as follows:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
        // Initialization code

        time=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 21)];
        time.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [time setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];
        [time setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [time addSubview:time];
        time.alpha=0.8;
    return  time;
}
```

but the frame does not appear in my MKmapView.

pls help me for this.

thanx in advance.

Comment: replace [time addSubview:time]; with [self addSubview:time];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just added time as a subView of itself, thats not going to do much. You want to add it as a subview of your MKMapView, or the view that MKMapView is on. If you add it after you add MKMapView it will appear over the MKMapView.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you adding the UILabel as a subview to itself? i.e. [time addSubview:time]; Perhaps it should be [self addSubview:time]; if you're currently in the view where you want the label to be added?